# Connecting MySQL installed on AWS EC2 instance with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed MySQL 5.7.25 on my AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04 AMI. I want to connect this MySQL instance with AWS Glue but I have been unable to do so. I have associated my EC2 instance with an elastic ip and tried connecting the MySQL instance by using a JDBC url with AWS Glue, but every time my connection is refused. Is there any way to connect the two?

Comment: Have you tried testing the connection before using it for your job?

Comment: Yes I had tested the connection and it was not connecting.

Comment: What's the error you are getting and can you try fixing it.If the connection is successful then only you can connect

Answer (score 2):

When creating the JDBC connection in aws glue,
1. Use JDBC url with private ip of your Ec2 instance(with mysql installed)

> jdbc:mysql://ec2_instance_private_ip:3306/database_name

2. Select the correct vpc and subnet where you Ec2 instance(with mysql installed) is located.
3. Select the same security group used for your Ec2 instance(with mysql installed)

Answer (score 0):

Before using AWS Glue, you should first use [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/dms/) to migrate your database. If your target database has a different schema than the source database, that's what we call heterogeneous database migrations, you need [AWS SCT](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/dms/schema-conversion-tool/#:~:text=WQF%20uses%20AWS%20Schema%20Conversion,them%20to%20an%20AWS%20database.).

One example of heterogeneous database migration is moving from an Oracle Database to PostgreSQL. As you see, the schema structure, data types, and database code of source databases are quite differents.